# Cakephp: Default validation

Tags: cakephp

I am sending a request to a User's controller. Both these methods return the same result:

```
$this->User->validates();
```

or

```
$this->User->set($this->request->data);
$this->User->validates();
```

Is it because `cakephp` is performing default validation on the request data?

How can I perform custom validation? Do I need to set a new data value?

Comment: check Cakephp document http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#adding-your-own-validation-methods

Answer (score 0):

cakephp validate only if you define validations in your model.

here is one example how to set validation in model.

```
/**
     * Validation
     *
     * @var array
     * @access public
     */
    public $validate = array(
        'first_name' => array(
            'notEmpty' => array(
                'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                'message' => 'This field cannot be left blank.',
                'last' => true,
            ),
            'size' => array(
                'rule' => array('maxLength', 50),
                'message' => 'This field must be no larger than 50 characters long.'
            ),
        ),
        'last_name' => array(
            'size' => array(
                'rule' => array('maxLength', 50),
                'message' => 'This field must be no larger than 50 characters long.',
                'allowEmpty' => true,
            ),
        ),
        'username' => array(
            'notEmpty' => array(
                'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                'message' => 'This field cannot be left blank.',
                'last' => true,
            ),
            'size' => array(
                'rule' => array('maxLength', 255),
                'message' => 'This field must be no larger than 255 characters long.'
            ),
            'isUnique' => array(
                'rule' => 'isUnique',
                'message' => 'The username has already been taken.',
                'last' => true,
            ),
        ),
);
```

and if you want your own validations you can do that.

```
 public $validate = array(
          'email' => array(
            'notEmpty' => array(
                'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                'message' => 'This field cannot be left blank.',
                'last' => true,
            ),

            'checkMail' => array(
                'rule' => 'checkMail',
                'message' => 'Please provide a valid email address.',
                'last' => true,
            ),
            'isUnique' => array(
                'rule' => 'isUnique',
                'message' => 'Email address already in use.',
                'last' => true,
            ),
        ),
    );

      /**
         * check email format
         */
        function checkMail() {
            $email = $this->data['User']['email'];
            $dotInString = substr_count(strstr($email, '@'), '.');

            if ($dotInString > 2)
                return false;

            if ($dotInString > 1)
                $preg_match_string = "/^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,2})+(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})+$/";
            else
                $preg_match_string = "/^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})+$/";

            if (preg_match($preg_match_string, $email) > 0) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

for more refer [cakephp validation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html)

Comment: I have the validation rules set, but I want to know whether Cakephp by default validates request data or some other data, basically does the request->data become the models active data by default or not.

Comment: if you are try to save any information only then validation has been called on the data which you are going to save.

Comment: if you still has doubt then provide more information in your question. According to your question it seems that you are asking about how validations fire and how to do custom validations.